# Open Layers point event

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Does anyone have an example of how to use an event handler with open layers point?

Thanks

```
    function mapCreate(lon,lat){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("map1");
        var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");
        map.addLayer(osm);
        var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
        );

        point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(center.lon,center.lat);
        vectors.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point)]);
        drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors);
        //map.addLayer(vectors);
        map.addControl(drag);
        drag.activate();
        map.setCenter(center, 15);
        map.addLayer(vectors);
        point.events.register('moveend',point, function(evt){
            alert('hello');
        });

    }
```

This is an example of what i have tried, for some reason this part does not work

```
point.events.register('moveend',point, function(evt){
                alert('hello');
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the code update, and I don't differentiate between a marker and a point, how do you? a marker is the thing that people use to identify a given point, no?

Comment: I differentiate between the two because point belongs to the vectors and marker does not. I think. From looking at the api for markers there is an event property which may solve my problem.

Comment: Ah, very good, I see what you mean there. Also, hopefully you can get it resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some similar code that I've used in the past to display a marker on hover on a list of divs on the right hand side of the page. Including it because it demonstrates how I've worked with the points in the past. I don't think it's quite what you want.

```
/* Included for per-item hovering from the paginated layer. */
function onFeatureSelected(event) {
    hoveredItem = $(this).attr('lookup');

    /* Do something here to indicate the onhover */
    // find the layer pagination id
    var feature = findFeatureById(hoveredItem);

    if (feature) {

        // use the pagination id to find the event, and then trigger the click for that event to show the popup
        // also, pass a null event, since we don't necessarily have one. 
        feature.marker.events.listeners.click[0].func.call(feature, event)
    }
}
function onFeatureUnselected(event) {
    /* Do something here to indicate the onhover */
    // find the layer pagination id
    var feature = findFeatureById(hoveredItem);

    if (feature) {

        // use the pagination id to find the event, and then trigger the click for that event to show the popup
        // also, pass a null event, since we don't necessarily have one. 
        feature.marker.events.listeners.click[0].func.call(feature, event)
    }

    /* Do something here to stop the indication of the onhover */

    hoveredItem = null;
}

function findFeatureById(featureId) {
    for (var key in map.layers) {
        var layer = map.layers[key];
        if (layer.hasOwnProperty('features')) {
            for (var key1 in layer.features) {
                var feature = layer.features[key1];
                if (feature.hasOwnProperty('id') && feature.id == featureId) {
                    return feature;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you're wanting to add this to the point as it is being created, I will have to refresh my memory on how that's been done in the past. Alternately, the GIS SE should be helpful to you.